# How To Create A Hyperlink For My Dialogflow Chatbot In Responses

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, kommunicate

I created a chatbot using dialogflow and I added a website link to the response, I have integrated the bot in Telegram and the website link is working perfectly, but on the web demo, it is not. Is it possible that when I integrate the chatbot on a website using Kommunicate, the hyperlink will work?

Comment: Dialogflow is not allowing the hyperlinks as web demo supports only plain text, you can have hypelinks with third party like botcopy or Kommunicate

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Will try that.

Answer (score 4):

Kommunicate has a link button template, create a Dialogflow intent using below metadata.

```
{
    "message": "click on the buttons",
    "platform":"kommunicate",
    "metadata": {
        "contentType": "300",
        "templateId": "3",
        "payload": [{
                "type": "link",
                "url": "https://www.google.com",
                "name": "Go To Google"
            },
            {
                "type": "link",
                "url": "https://www.facebook.com",
                "name": "Go To Facebook",
                "openLinkInNewTab": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The *openLinkInNewTab: false* to open any link in the same tab. Default value is true, which will open the links in the new tab. 
[Here](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/message-types#link-button) is more information about the same.

Also, you can render HTML content as a message and Kommunicate will render the HTML in the UI. [Here](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/message-types#send-html-content) is the metadata for that.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the web demo only supports plain text responses, so adding an clickable url within your chatbot for the webdemo isn't possible. Luckily, this is a limitation for web demo, so any other integration that do support URL's in their chats will work as you have seen with Telegram.

Comment: But is it possible that when I integrate the chatbot on a website that without using the web demo, it works?

Comment: Yes, links will work in any other integration that do support URL's.