# Link in dialogflow chatbot using kommunicate

Tags: button, hyperlink, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm so much trying to integrate `links` in my chatbot using `dialogflow`.

I tried to integrate it using `'kommunicate'`. but I can't insert the key value in kommunicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59894557/1202324

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Create A Hyperlink For My Dialogflow Chatbot In Responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856688/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-for-my-dialogflow-chatbot-in-responses)

Answer (score 1):

Kommunicate supports Rich message - Link buttons, where you need to use the JSON code on the custom payload section of the Dialogflow intent. Please to refer this [doc](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/message-types#link-button) for more details.